# GCE Ubuntu mirrors officially supported?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Are the Ubuntu mirrors in GCE (e.g. `europe-west1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com`) officially supported? I was not able to find a definitive answer to that, despite some googling.

Comment: Google does not support Ubuntu mirrors. But, if you want support from Ubuntu you can contact them [from](https://ubuntu.com/support).

Comment: @AbhijithChitrapu I meant more like does Google somewhere commit to keep this mirror running and updated.

Comment: This image is hosted on ubuntu.com, it means it's hosted, maintained and supported by canonical servers. The only thing you can do from your side is to open a ticket with canonical.